# How to delete user directory on Windows 7's Explorer?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

[image]

In the screenshot above, you can see that my Explorer shows the 'Moon' directory all the time. How can I hide it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`moon` seems to be your user account; if the Explorer pane is set to show all items, this comes up.

[image]

---

Right click the Explorer pane and uncheck Show all folders - it won't be shown.

[image]